# Handling "Allow Camera to access device's location" prior to login

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app that uses the phone's camera to take pictures. Upon install and launching the camera on the emulator for the first time, the following permission is requested:

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjGbn.png)

It is a bit disruptive to the app. I already have other permissions set on the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And on the main activity prior to login:

```
private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,
                new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE );
    }
```

Is there a way to make the request "Allow Camera to access this device's location" alongside with my other permissions before a user is allowed to log in?

I have also attempted to request permission for the fine location:

```
private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,
                new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE );
    }
```

Which grants my app, and not the camera, the permission beforehand which doesn't really solve my problem. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for late reply but I was a bit confused about this myself:

I think this is not actually your app asking for permission, but rather the android camera app asking for permission, so there is not much to do. If you were to launch the camera app on a clean emulator you would get the same result.

Hopefully though your apps users will already have used the camera before installing you app and this shouldn't be a problem. :)